# subqueries with select

Tags: subquery

This below query works as expected:

```
SELECT 
    reports.* 
FROM
    reports 
    INNER JOIN 
        units 
        ON units.id = reports.unit_id 
WHERE 
    reports.unit_id IN (1111, 1112, 1113) 
    AND 
    (
        reports.id = 
        (
            SELECT reports.id 
            FROM reports
            WHERE reports.unit_id = units.id 
            ORDER BY time desc
            LIMIT 1
        )
    )
```

It returns the last 3 reports associated with the given units by time. How come that SELECT subquery returns 3 ids rather than just 1 even though we specifiy LIMIT 1? This is what I wanted. I'm just curious how it works.

Comment: The LIMIT is only limiting the innermost query. The outer one is free to return lots of rows based on the single row you're feeding it

Comment: @Phil but how does the inner query know about the out filter of 3 unit ids?

Comment: It doesn't. It's a correlated subquery which means it runs as many times as the rows that are generated by the `FROM ... WHERE` clauses (which are 3 here.)

Comment: Correction: The rows generated by the `FROM` clause, even after restricting with the first condition in the `WHERE` may be more than 3. But the distinct `unit.id` values in those rows are 3 and these values are used inside the correlated subquery. Whether the DBMS runs the subquery 3 or a million times depends on the implemenation (read optimizer.)